# java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject error in android 2.2

Tags: android, json

hi i have problem in json parsing in android 2.2 
and i don't have this problem in android 4

my error is java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

please help me

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            result =JsonParser.readUrl("http://192.168.1.3/json2.txt");
        }
    }).start();
    while (result==null){
    }

    try {
        Log.i("resilt",result);
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray anotherArray = object.getJSONArray("tabs");
        for (int i = 0; i < anotherArray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject tab = anotherArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String title = tab.getString("title");
            titlelist.add(title);
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

public class JsonParser {

```
public static String readUrl(String url) {
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost method = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(method);
        int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        Log.i("LOG", "Code: " + code);
        InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        String result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);

        return result;
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}


private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) {
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

{"tabs":[{"title":"123"},{"title":"1203"}]}

Comment: Can you post your String(may be result={"tabs":[{"title":"123"},{"title":"1203"}]})

Comment: i found it , my json format file is txt but it must be .php